# TFS 2010 Test Agent registration on a Test Controller

Tags: testing, automated-tests

I´ve setup a Test Controller and several Test Agents on VMs. I was able to connect to the Test Controller with every Test Agent except the one installed on a Windows 7 Starter edition. Problem is obvious. Win 7 Starter can not join the domain where the PC hosting the Test Controller is located. How can i get around this problem? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you tried so far? There's a number of resources that talk about cross domain issues.

Try **2.2. Controller/Agent in untrusted Windows domains or one is in a workgroup and another one is in domain.**

**From:** http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/vststest/thread/df043823-ffcf-46a4-9e47-1c4b8854ca13

- Mirror user account on Controller and Agent: create a user account with same user name and password on both Controller and Agent machine.
- Use mirrored user account to run Controller and Agent services under this account.
- If you are using VS2010 RC+ version (i.e. RC or RTM but not Beta2), add the following line to the qtcontroller.exe.config file under the appSettings node:

<add key="AgentImpersonationEnabled" value="no"/>

- Restart Controller/Agent services (see Tools section in the Appendix).
  Make sure there is no IP Security Policy that prevents the connection (see IP Security Policy under Tools section in the Appendix).
- By default for domain machines Windows uses domain (Kerberos) authentication, but if it fails it will fall back to workgroup (NTLM) authentication. This behavior can be and often is altered by IP Security policies, for instance, there could be a policy to block connections from machines which do not belong to the domain.
- Restart or re-configure Controller and Agent.

Or **Running Tests cross domain with TFS and Visual Studio 2010**
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dustin_andrews/archive/2010/08/12/running-tests-cross-domain-with-tfs-and-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Comment: If AgentImpersonationEnabled, then you probably don't need to mirror the accounts.

Comment: @RyanRiehle wouldn't that require a domain account?

Comment: Recently set this up with a client of ours and it worked in VS/TFS 2012;  the controller was on the domain; test agent clients were not and were auto-provisioned using Hyper-V/ TFS Lab management.  No phantom accounts necessary.  Account running the auto-provision was the local .\administrator account on the workgroup machines.

Answer (score 1):

There is one problem with Mirroring Accounts for both Test Controller and Test Agent,  it will not work if you register your controller to TFS team collection.
Why? Cause if you run your Test Controller and Test Agent under workgroup account,TFS server will disconnect the Test Controller cause authentication issue. If you ran Test Controller under domain account and Agent under workgroup then Test Agent will not be authenticated by Test controller.
Unless I am missing something it will not work if you need your Test Controller to be register to TFS team collection.